# Shutting down computer from emacs killing gracefully emacs itself

Tags: window, process, shell-command

I am using [EXWM](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/) on Arch as my windows manager. Substantially my `startx` launches
`exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs` so I am running only emacs and living inside it. I would like to define a function `shutdown` to properly handle the shutdown of my computer terminating
every process in a graceful way. This function has to:

1. Execute `(save-some-buffers)`
2. Check in every frame if there are running processes that I've personally started
3. Ask if I want to continue
4. Send `SIGHUP` to each of these process
5. Check if those process have quit, if not send them a stronger signal
6. Exit emacs
7. Shutdown the computer

I want to kill processes with `SIGHUP`, which is the signal `(kill-buffer)`
sends, because using `(save-buffer-kill-emacs)` kills them too brutally.
For example Chromium always asks me if I want to restore previous session,
whereas killing Chromium with `SIGHUP` makes it restore the correct session the
next time I start it.
I want to properly quit emacs before shutting down the computer because if I use `(shell-command "shutdown now")` it prevents emacs to correctly run every exit-hook (for
example it doesn't remove the `desktop-file.lock` of `(desktop-save-mode)`.
My workaround for this problem is to schedule a shutdown 3 seconds in the
future, so emacs can properly quit, but it is not very elegant.

How can I do?

Comment: Any reason you can't just add an exit-hook that runs `(shell-command "shutdown now")` between steps 5 and 6?

Comment: That could be a solution, but I have to be sure that there aren't any hooks after the one that runs `shutdown now`

Comment: With `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook '(shell-command "shutdown now"))` the command is executed as first. How can I rearrange the order?

Comment: do `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook '(shell-command "shutdown now") t)` instead. the `t` is an optional argument for "append"

Comment: Now it's working as expected. And how can I change the signal I send to processes?